# Does Opera not apply `noopener` to `target="_blank"` by default?

Tags: html, opera

Modern browsers now apply `rel="noopener"` behavior automatically to links when `target="_blank"` is present. However, according to the [MDN browser compatability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#browser_compatibility), Opera still does not do this.

This seems very strange to me, as Opera is based on Chromium, and I would have thought that this sort of update would have been made to Chromium, rather than the proprietary Chrome wrapping around it. Can anyone confirm that Opera *DOES NOT* apply `noopener` behavior to `target="_blank"` automatically? (And even better, why not?)

Comment: Not quite. To avoid confusion, you get the same behavior but browsers do not apply attributes to your HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/noopener

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - that's not Opera-specific, is it? I'm concerned with what Opera specifically is doing differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: The compatibility table has now been [fixed](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/17607#issuecomment-1846612289). Opera has the correct behavior of `target="_blank" implies rel="noopener" behavior` like all the other modern browsers.

---

**Old answer**:

Seems like the compatibility table is wrong about Opera's `target="_blank" implies rel="noopener" behavior` (it should say "Yes"). There is an open issue about it: https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/17607

According to the reporter, the behavior is present since at least Opera 90.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Assuming the issue is correct, that solves the mystery!!